# Python selenium child class opens a new browser window - how to prevent this?

Tags: python, selenium, class, inheritance, parent-child

I am trying to create a child class for my selenium browser. Here is my code:

```
class SeleniumDriver:
    """Class that represents a game."""
    def __init__(self):
        # start Tor browser
        self.profile_path = r'C:\Tor Browser2\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default'
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.binary_location = r'C:\Tor Browser2\Browser\firefox.exe'
        self.options.set_preference('profile', self.profile_path)
        self.service = Service('C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe')
        self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service, options=self.options)

class Items(SeleniumDriver):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    # More methods that do stuff....
```

When I initialize both classes, the child class starts a new browser window. How can I make it attach to existing/parent initialized browser? I tried separating "self.driver = Firefox" to another method, but then child class throws:

```
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to resolve this.

But generally, you should think do you really need inheritance?

##### Why not Delegation?

If you just want to use the driver, launched by some class, then add  `driver` as an argument to the constructor, or even add `SeleniumDriver` as an argument.

See https://erikscode.space/index.php/2020/08/01/delegate-and-decorate-in-python-part-1-the-delegation-pattern/

*With driver as an argument*

```
class SeleniumDriver:

    driver = None

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service, options=self.options)

class Items:

    driver = None

    # parameterized constructor
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

...
seleniumDriver = SeleniumDriver()
itemsObj = Items(seleniumDriver.driver)
```

*With SeleniumDriver as argument*

```
class Items:

    seleniumDriver = None

    # parameterized constructor
    def __init__(self, seleniumDriver):
        self.seleniumDriver = seleniumDriver

...

seleniumDriver = SeleniumDriver()
itemsObj = Items(seleniumDriver)
```

##### Stay using inheritance

For this case, I suggest moving out this line from the constructor

```
self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service, options=self.options)
```

to the separate `start_driver` method:

```
class SeleniumDriver:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.profile_path = r'C:\Tor Browser2\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default'
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.binary_location = r'C:\Tor Browser2\Browser\firefox.exe'
        self.options.set_preference('profile', self.profile_path)
        self.service = Service('C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe')

    def start_driver(self):
        self.driver = Firefox(service=self.service, options=self.options)


class Items(SeleniumDriver):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def with_driver(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

...
seleniumDriver = SeleniumDriver()
seleniumDriver.start_driver()

itemsObj = Items()
itemsObj.with_driver(seleniumDriver.driver)
```

or add driver arg to constructor:

```
class Items(SeleniumDriver):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__()
        self.driver = driver

...
seleniumDriver = SeleniumDriver()
seleniumDriver.start_driver()
itemsObj = Items(seleniumDriver.driver) #make sure start_driver() already invoked on seleniumDriver
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation. I am new to python and have not heard about Delegation before. However I would like to use inheritance in my case. When i try to do that in the using inheritance suggestion that you provided, the 'self' in "self.driver = driver" in Items class says Unresolved reference 'self'.

Comment: Sorry, haven't run this in ide.. I'll try to run this code and update my answer tomorrow.. I'll ping you.

Comment: @RuslanAli-zade, I've updated the answer. `def with_driver(self, driver)` should be instead of `def with_driver(driver)`.

Comment: Thank you for the update! It works flawlessly now. Truly appreciate you taking  your time to help.

Comment: @RuslanAli-zade you can accept the answer if it's helpful enough, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work